# How to truncate text in kendo's expansion panel component

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a very simple, but quite tricky, question: I need to display a title of a post using kendo's expansion panel component in Angular. The tricky part is that I don't want it to exceed the length of 10 characters. The code I wrote is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <kendo-expansionpanel
      *ngFor="let data of datas"
      [title]="data.title | slice:0:6"
      [subtitle]="'from ' + data.userId"
      [expanded]="false"
      class="col-6">
        <span class="content-text">{{data.body}}</span>
    </kendo-expansionpanel>
  </div>
```

I thought that the line:

`[title]="data.title | slice:0:6"`

would work, but I keep getting the error:

Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

How can I solve it?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code and `[title]="data.title | slice:0:6"` should work. Could you please provide a stackblitz reproduction of the error?